# Android Studio on Chromebook with crouton-script (ARM-architecture)

Tags: android, chromebook

I have a Chromebook from Acer with an ARM-Architecture (ARM7 => 32bit, I think)

I want to use the [Android Studio IDE](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

So I downloaded it and tried to install, but it didn't work.

The error message says:

> Unable to run `mksdcard` SDK tool

After some research I realised that the problem is that I installed the 64bit-architecture version and I have to install the 32bit libs (my architecture is ARM) with

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

However, I am not able to install these libs. I think that the reason is my ARM-Architecture.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem?

My operating system: `ARM7-Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` (installed using [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton))

Comment: Why are you *not able to install these libs*? Is there an error message?

Comment: Hello, yes - the error message is: "has noch installation candidate"

Comment: I doubt someone is going to read this, but the reason this is not working is that armhf and i386 architectures aer not compatible. armhf  (Acorn Reduced Instruction Set Computer Machine Hard Float, if you wonder) is an entirely different processor architecture than i386 (Intel 386 and compatibles, like modern PCs), and despite both being 32-bit, binary software (like you get from apt-get) for one of them can't be used in the other. You might have better luck searching for a binary for armhf, or maybe compile the neccisary software yourself, if you're feeling adventurous.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem myself.
Yes you cannot run Android Studio because you are on an ARM processor which has a limited instruction set..

Android studio requires an intel based architecture given that it is 64bit processor (AMD64 as called by debian).. It will then give you the same error message regarding mksdcard until you ADD a 'foreign' architecture manually using dpkg. Once you do this.. you have to update apt with apt-get update...

This is not really foreign however because i386 is easily understood by a 64bit intel processors.

Since your ARM7HF (I'm assuming hard float processor) lacks the same design. it's like asking you to drive a car when all you have is a bike, it won't work even though you did download and run the program installer initially because you were using oracles JAVA which DOES have a hard float version..

I'm not sure why Google doesn't port Android studio over to the ARM architecture given that many chrome OS laptops are running on ARM nowadays anyway... so they would benefit from people who want to run linux dual boot and develop software for android.

Can anyone else add in their thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Carl, and welcome to StackOverflow. Since this isn't a discussion forum, but rather a Q&A site, you might want to edit your post to remove the reference to asking for additional answers in the last line - just to save people misinterpreting your answer as another question (this does happen often here). Thanks!